Summing over a list of lists
I would like to sum over the following:
list1 = {{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}}
Sum[a + b, "over list1"]

What is the syntax for that?
Edit:
I would like the output to be
Sum[a + b, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}]
= 4

but without specifying explicitly the two lists, but simply using the variable list1.

Total@{{a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}}?

On a second thought maybe you meant Sum[a + b, Evaluate[Sequence @@ list1]]? Or simply Sum[a + b, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}].

maybe Total[Total[list1]] is simpler than Sum[a + b, Evaluate[Sequence @@ list1]] but it gives 2 + a + b.  It would be easier if OP showed what they wanted as final answer instead of one having to guess.

Please edit your question to include the expected output.

Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory book written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a fast intro for math students as well as a fast intro for programmers to choose from.

Thanks, for the answer. Indeed, I was looking for the expression Sum[a + b, Evaluate[Sequence @@ list1]]. I have edited the question above.
